# ls command messy output

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I use zsh. Today I found when typing `ls`,the output layout in a weird way, It should be list in a column, but it shows like this:

[image]

It seems that each item is separated by tab rather than newline.

Comment: That's not a question.

Comment: @ash  Actually, only when you not meet it

Comment: the new image you added looks doesn't look like it's a tabbing issue, but rather that it's word-wrapping onto the next line. That sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a way to solve it. I copied a `ls` program in '/bin' from my friend's computer, and it's OK now.

Answer (score 0):

use `ls -l` to list each item on a newline

Answer (score 0):

There is a wonderful manual in $PATH that will assist you with most of the utilities in Linux/UNIX;  ~> man ls